# Executing batch file in cmd.exe does nothing

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, windows-xp

On a Windows XP machine SP3, using an account with Administrator rights, I try to execute a simple batch file, named test.bat, that contains:

```
echo Hello!
```

Using cmd.exe, I get this result:

```
D:\Dev>test.bat

D:\Dev>
```

This indicates that the batch file is not executed at all: it returns immediately.

Can you tell me why it does that?

Comment: Try including some invalid syntax in the batch file; does it produce an error?

Comment: test may be a reserved word. Whynot name it myTest.bat to eliminate that worry? Also, some shells get all excited when they see a '!' char, I would remove that, just to be eliminate that as an issue. Finally, try calling your script like `.\myTest.bat`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - test should not cause a problem. I routinely use "test.bat" for quick batch development work. The `!` only has special significance if delayed expansion is enabled, and even then, the only impact would be the `!` would be eliminated from the output.

Comment: Are you sure "test.bat" exists in your "D:\Dev" folder?

Comment: Try with another batch containing some other commands (Cd Dir whatever). Just to prove if it's limited to this batch or is a more global problem

Comment: Assuming test.bat is indeed in D:\dev, what is the effect of the command `D:\dev\test.bat`?   I'm poking at the idea it might be a path lookup problem, though it's not one I'm familiar with: I'd expect the local dir to be first, always.  (Oh, I see shellter said much the same thing - sorry for repetition)

Comment: Thank you all for your replies:

Comment: Here are the answers to your suggestions in chronological order: with invalid syntax, it still does nothing. Renaming test.bat for myTest.bat does not work. Using .\myTest.bat does not work. test.bat exists in my D:\Dev folder. Even with any command (cd, echo, ...), it still does nothing. Even with the full path, D:\dev\test.bat, it doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting, when I do "dir" directly in the shell, some characters are not interpreted correctly and the last e of free is missing (ex: 3 Dir(s)  892Â 258Â 992Â 128 bytes fre). Maybe it's a bug in the shell that causes the batch file problem?

Comment: try issuing the `set` command and examining all of your env-vars. Is there anything like LC_LOCALE. Is this your personal PC, or a corporate PC that might contain a lot of setup stuff that you have no control over? Good luck.

Comment: See if you can directly execute `echo Hello!` on the prompt

Comment: echo Hello! works when typed directly on the prompt, but not from a batch file.

Comment: I don't have a LC_LOCALE environment variable; it's a corporate computer where I have all the rights to modify its configuration.

Comment: Try to create a new batch file from the prompt, 'echo echo hello > test2.bat' perhaps you created an unicodeFile. And please show us the result of 'chcp' from the command line

Comment: What is your D:\ Dirve? Mainly, is it a USB, internal Hard Drive ect. Ive tested this myself on my school PC (no admin rights) and with Command.com, and it works just fine. Also, i cant remeber, but im sure there was something like this related to setting in WinXP, which caused Echo not to work correctly

Comment: chcp shows Active code page: 850. Event if I set it to 437 (United States), it doesn't work.

Comment: My D drive is an internal hard drive. And echo echo hello > test2.bat works.

Answer (score 2):

Run into your console:

```
D:\Dev> echo echo Hello! > test.bat
D:\Dev> test.bat
```

If it works (and it probably will), you are doing something wrong.

To figure out what's happening with yout file you can also try

```
D:\Dev> more test.bat
```

To see what's inside test.bat file.

Comment: It works now for a shell command manually executed, but it didn't work before: I'm really suspecting a Windows XP bug. The commands that are calling batch files and are executed automatically and remotely by Twisted are still not working, though.

Comment: @GDICommander - you could compare the _shell created_ `shelltest.bat` with your old `test.bat` with `fc /b shelltest.bat test.bat`, I assume that their are different (ex UTF coded)

Answer (score 1):

One issue that I had was when I used UTF-16 encoding in Vim. Generally `more` will either show your code or character by character one very line. Changing to UTF-8 helped.

Comment: I encountered something similar. I created bat file with right click: new txt. But instead i created new rar. No worry I modified the extension, edit the file, but yeah it never ran properly.